# AngularJS : Refreshing only one div which comes from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have number of divs in a page. Each div containing different id.
In each and every div some high charts are present and also some link for filtering the result.
Each div comes from the ng-repeat of the angularJS as:

`<li id="{{record.id}} "ng-repeat = "record in records">`:

One of the div inside this list is like following structure:

```
<div id="criteria">
    <!--Calling a Pie chart that works fine -->
    <a href="#" onclick="edit();">
</div>
```

My script on the same page is like:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
function edit(){
    var criteria=prompt("Please enter criteria");
    if (criteria=="Login")
       {
       $("#criteria").load("Loginbar.html");
       }      
    }
</script>
```

Now my question is when i click on edit it will ask the criteria and when i entered Login the pie chart replaced by the loginbar chart but at that time whole page is getting refreshed.

I want that only the div having id="criteria" will be refreshed.

I already tried following but this is not working:

```
 $("#criteria").html();
```

Need for Help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<a href="#" onclick="edit(); return false;">
```